# Acceptable ranges for Solr bias values

Tags: search, solr

I've been doing a lot of work recently with applying bias in Solr when searching in order to get more relevant results, and one thing I'm curious about is the acceptable range of bias values. For instance, in one Solr implementation I've seen, the value of applicable bias values ranges from 0.1 to 21.0, with intermediate values of 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0, and 13.0. In another place, I've seen a max value of 100. In everything I've read, I've never seen a definition of acceptable value ranges. Is there such a thing? I'm guessing that there are some complex mathematical concepts behind biasing, so I'm also wondering what best practices are when it comes to defining bias value ranges.

Another question along these lines, does the difference between bias values come into play? For instance, if I have two field **title** and **body**, and in my qf param I add

```
title^8 body^2
```

does that mean that the **title** field has 4x more weight than the **body** field, or would adding

```
title^3 body^2
```

have the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append `debugQuery=true` to any query to see exactly how each field contributes to the calculated score.

The weights given in `qf` is multiplied with the score calculated for the match, so `title^8` will contribute more to the final score from the `title` field than what `title^3` does.

This can be quickly tested. With `^2.0`:

```
(MATCH) max of:\n    0.13514908 = (MATCH) weight(field:term^2.0 in 36)
```

With `^4.0`:

```
(MATCH) max of:\n    0.27026632 = (MATCH) weight(field:term^4.0 in 36)
```

.. which is exactly twice as much.

So `^8` vs `^2` would mean that the first field is weighed four times heavier than the second field.

Be aware that this comparison works here because the same query normalization is used for both queries (which would not be the case of there is a far larger difference between the boost values - scores across queries isn't really comparable).

Acceptable values are within the range of a double, and "best practices" is to experiment to get the matching profile you're looking for. There is no hard science to this, but you'll have to tweak the values (and there are machine learning options for this if you have enough signals) to get the result list you want.